# Check a PHP file for syntax errors

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-checking

I'm attempting to build an auditing feature into my application that will check for various code quality issues.

One of the things I would like to do is check certain PHP files for syntax errors.  I was going to use [php_check_syntax()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php) but it has been removed in PHP 5.0.5.

I've tried using `exec()` statements but it isn't outputting anything.  I've added a `date` to make sure `exec()` is working:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$output = 'before';
var_dump($output);
var_dump(exec('php -l ' . __FILE__, $output));
var_dump($output);
var_dump(exec('date', $output));
var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string 'before' (length=6)
string '' (length=0)
array (size=0)
  empty
string 'Thu Feb  6 10:42:35 PST 2014' (length=28)
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Thu Feb  6 10:42:35 PST 2014' (length=28)
```

How can I check a PHP file for syntax errors in PHP?

Comment: Did you check the command directly first? (To make sure the path is correct, and that the php command works correctly)

Comment: Make sure you're validating that path correctly.

Comment: The path is correct and the command works in terminal.  I've tried `/usr/bin/php` as well

Comment: check php error logs and add the following to the top of php file
`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_WARNING);`
`@ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: if it is working from the terminal and not through your web server, be sure that exec is enabled. Maybe you are running in safe mode?

Comment: `exec()` is working.  I've updated my question with a better test case.

Comment: `php -l` _will_ give you a proper return value which indicates good or bad... Try it on a broken file, and make sure you use `exec`'s `$return_var`.

Answer (score 2):

check web-server configuration. 
places like this: disable_functions="".
after var_dump($output) starts to return an array check for errors in array to eliminate further errors like correct path to php.

use this to eliminate some other possibilities:

```
$output="just before exec";
var_dump($output);
exec('php -l /path/to/file.php', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

p.s. may be used like

```
echo exec('php -l /path/to/file.php');
```

Upd: Updated question shows exec works.
It may be your *nix like platform hides the error output.
a way to redirect it to add to the command 2>&1
it will redirect error output into standard output

```
$to_run = '/path/to/bin/php -l /path/to/file 2>&1';
$output ="" ; //init
var_dump(exec($to_run, $output));
```

if you have root access on the platform you may even use tools like strace
to debug some complicated cases.

```
'/path/to/bin/strace -o/path/to/strace.log php -l /path/to/file.php'
```

UPD: var_dump(exec('php -l ' . FILE .' 2>&1', $output)); // error redirection for a unix platform

Comment: I've tried this an updated my question.  It's still not working.

Comment: var_dump(exec('php -l ' . __FILE__ .' 2>&1', $output)); // error redirection for a unix platform

Answer (score 1):

To check many php files, you can save this code as a batch file and execute it:

```
echo php files error check report >output.txt
for /r %%i in (*.php) do ( echo. & php -l %%i  )  >>output.txt
start "" "output.txt"
```

Save it as "check.bat" (for example) in the php files directory and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Unix bash script you could use to syntax check all .php files in folder and subfolder:

```bash
find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep '^No syntax errors' -v  | less
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Fake51/865603

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with lint running PHP with the [`-l`](http://php.net/manual/de/features.commandline.options.php) parameter on the command line:

**`test.php`**:

```
<?php
phpinfo()
```

result:

```
$ php -l test.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in test.php on line 2
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in test.php on line 2
Errors parsing test.php
```

**`test.php`**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

result:

```
$ php -l test.php
No syntax errors detected in test.php
```