# how check entire folder against problems in vscode php?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I am using PHP Intelephense I want to check the entire project for problems but it seems to run only on opened files.

I tried to open multiple files using other plugins but it is not efficient to do so as I have to go through each folder one by one.

Any idea how to accomplish that may be using other plugin or tool?

Comment: I also couldn't find any specific tool to Visual Code to do this, but you can accomplish a similar result by calling PHP executable directly to syntax check all .php files in folder and subfolder. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592524/check-a-php-file-for-syntax-errors/

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to do that with VSCode. But I can suggest you download [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download) that comes with a 30-day trial.
[image: PhpStorm PHP files error check feature]

It has a built-in PHP error check feature. It checks for errors in all PHP files that are in your project folder.
It also has Search in Files feature that lets you quickly search for a word or phrase in all your Project files.
You can give it a try. PhpStorm has a lot of features that VSCode does not have.